# Playing audio in python at given timestamp

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to find a way in python to play a section of an audio file given a start and end time.

For example, say I have an audio file that is 1 min in duration. I want to play the section from 0:30 to 0:45 seconds.

I do not want to process or splice the file, only playback of the given section.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I found a great solution using pydub:

https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

audiofile = #path to audiofile
start_ms = #start of clip in milliseconds
end_ms = #end of clip in milliseconds

sound = AudioSegment.from_file(audiofile, format="wav")
splice = sound[start_ms:end_ms]
play(splice)
```

Answer (score 0):

step one is to get your python to play entire audio file ... several libraries are available for this ... see if the library has a time specific api call ... you can always roll up your sleeves and implement this yourself after you read the audio file into a buffer or possibly stream the file and stop streaming at end of chosen time section

Another alternative is to leverage command line tools like ffmpeg which is the Swiss Army Knife of audio processing ... ffmpeg has command line input parms to do time specific start and stop ... also look at its sibling ffplay

Similar to ffplay/ffmpeg is another command line audio tool called sox

Comment: I looked into ffplay and found pydub, which is a great solution. Many thanks!

Comment: @jordansilva What is that solution their docs is not specific enough.

Comment: @MattQuaine did you look at the question at top ... there is an Update showing code to play an audio file from specific start + stop

Answer (score 0):

Use [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org//index.html) and [Player](http://pymedia.org/docs/pymedia.player.html). Look at the functions SeekTo() and SeekEndTime(). I think you will be able to find a right solution after playing around with these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble installing external libraries and if you are running your code on a server and you don't have sudo privileges then it becomes even more cumbersome. Don't even get me started on ffmpeg installation.
So, here's an alternative solution with scipy and native IPython that avoids the hassle of installing some other library.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile # to read and write audio files
import IPython #to play them in jupyter notebook without the hassle of some other library

def PlayAudioSegment(filepath, start, end, channel='none'):
    
    # get sample rate and audio data
    sample_rate, audio_data = wavfile.read(filepath) # where filepath = 'directory/audio.wav'
    
    #get length in minutes of audio file
    print('duration: ', audio_data.shape[0] / sample_rate / 60,'min')
    
    ## splice the audio with prefered start and end times
    spliced_audio = audio_data[start * sample_rate : end * sample_rate, :]
        
    ## choose left or right channel if preferred (0 or 1 for left and right, respectively; or leave as a string to keep as stereo)
    spliced_audio = spliced_audio[:,channel] if type(channel)==int else spliced_audio 
        
    ## playback natively with IPython; shape needs to be (nChannel,nSamples)
    return IPython.display.Audio(spliced_audio.T, rate=sample_rate)
```

Use like this:

```
filepath = 'directory_with_file/audio.wav'
start = 30 # in seconds
end = 45 # in seconds
channel = 0 # left channel
PlayAudioSegment(filepath,start,end,channel)
```